# Drop 'NaN' and single quote item in a list

Tags: python, numpy

The objective is to drop 'NaN' and single quote item in a list. I am using numpy, but it is not working.

**Input:**

```
abc=[['mai', 'dubai', '200ml', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN'],
     ['nestle', '', 'nido', 'milk', 'powder', '', '2.5kg', '(n1)', 'NaN'],
     ['al', 'alali', 'mushroom', 'pieces', '&', 'stems', '400gm', 'NaN', 'NaN'],
     ['mai', 'dubai', 'cup', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN']]


x = abc[~np.isnan(abc)]


TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

**Expected Output:**

```
abc=[['mai', 'dubai', '200ml'],
     ['nestle', 'nido', 'milk', 'powder', '2.5kg', '(n1)'],
     ['al', 'alali', 'mushroom', 'pieces', 'stems', '400gm'],
     ['mai', 'dubai', 'cup']]
```

Thank you

Comment: `NaN` is a string. Whatever you've done, you've created an array of strings. `x = abc[abc != 'NaN]]`

Comment: @ roganjosh: yes, it is

Comment: Judging by the error, it looks like `np.isnan` does not work on nested arrays. have you checked its documentation? Either way,  if your "NaN" values are the string `'NaN'` as been pointed out, `np.isnan` is not going to work anyway

Comment: Well, the string `NaN` is not the same as `np.nan` so you can't use it to filter strings

Comment: yes, so please tell me how to get the expected output from the input. Thank you!

Comment: ... I already did. It's in my first comment. You've since decided to expand the title to include empty strings, but I'd already fixed the first problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using numpy you can use a list comprehension and a [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)

```
exclude = ('', 'NaN')
[list(filter(lambda x: x not in exclude, l)) for l in abc]
```

Comment: This will be really slow compared to a numpy approach

Comment: Wonderful. I just updated my input. Kindly let me know how to drop single quote as well. thanks

Comment: Updated to allow for multiple values to exclude. If the result of this is to be iterated over after filtering I would not convert the filter to a list for a slightly faster solution

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do a simple list comprehension.

```
result = [[i for i in x if i != 'NaN' and i != ''] for x in abc]

[['mai', 'dubai', '200ml'],
 ['nestle', 'nido', 'milk', 'powder', '2.5kg', '(n1)'],
 ['mai', 'dubai', 'cup']]
```